# TFS Email templates - view XSLT errors

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS2015.

I made a change to `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 14.0\Application Tier\TFSJobAgent\Transforms\1033\BuildCompletedEvent.xsl` and now I'm no longer getting email alerts.  So presumably, an error in my .xsl, but I can't seem to find any documentation on where such errors would get logged to.

I looked in the database at  `[Tfs_Configuration].[dbo].[tbl_JobHistory]` but I see nothing relevant.

Worse, I reverted my changes and I'm still not getting email alerts.  Unclear how to figure out what I did wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you checked in event viewer? Application and Service Logs > Microsoft Team Foundation Server > Debug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  If there's an XSL transform error, it gets mailed to you as the notification.  I had another notification issue which was preventing emails from getting to me at all.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to diagnose Email Alert logs with below command:

```
-diagnosing-email-and-soap-subscription-failures/
```

More detail steps and info please refer this blog from MSDN: [TFS2010: Diagnosing Email and SOAP subscription failures](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/granth/2009/10/28/tfs2010-diagnosing-email-and-soap-subscription-failures/)